# Finding the orthogonal complement of a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard inner product and let $U=Sp\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}\}$. Find the orthogonal complement $U^{\perp}$ of $U$.

Attempt: We need to find the set of vectors $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$ which are perpendicular to the set of vectors in $U$. In other words, their dot product is zero. Hence $x+y-2z=0$, the plane, is the orthogonal complement. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Shouldn't you have $x+y+2z = 0 $ instead of $x+y-2z = 0$ !?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the equation is $x+y+2z=0$.
Since $U$ has dimension 1, the orthogonal complement should have dimension 3-1=2.
Just take two vectors which are linearly independent and satisfy the above equation, like $(1,-1,0)^T$ and $(2,0,-1)^T$.